# Laravel unable to retrieve the correct current page no. which result pagination is not working(showing the first page result only)

Tags: laravel, pagination

Let us consider an example

https://www.example.net/xyz?page=2

```
Route::get('/xyz', 'controller@getpages'); 

public function getpages() {
  $variable=Model::paginate(10);
  dd($variable);
}
```

i have done "dd($variable);" in function . which gives the result of

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#1209 ▼
#total: 4341
#lastPage: 435
#items: Collection {#1211 ▶}
#perPage: 10
#currentPage: 1
#path: "www.example.net/xyz"
#query: []
#fragment: null
#pageName: "page"
}
```

dd($request);

```
Request {#38 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#1028 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#1029 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#40 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#46 ▶}
  +query: ParameterBag {#46 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#42 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#43 ▶}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#41 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#44 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/xyz"
  #requestUri: "/xyz?page=2"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#112 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isForwardedValid: true
}
```

dd($request->all());

it is showing

```
array:1 [▼
  "/xyz" => null
]
```

in the site which have error. but rest of the sites whose pagination working properly . gives the below output.

```
array:1 [▼
 "page" => "2"
]
```

instead of **#currentPage: 2** . it was working properly, But from yesterday it is happening like this through all our site. so how can I fix this?

Note: I have used this same code in multipage sites. but it is not working in it only

i got the proper issue here.In our whole site the passing to controller . and in validation . it is not mention how can i resolve this.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: please add some more codes. what is $variable? how do you initializing it? please provide some more

Comment: wait i am adding to it

Comment: you can see the rest of the codes

Comment: can you show your route?

Comment: added the route also

Comment: do you use API resources?

Comment: yes, but how can i recognize that API which is affecting to this?

Comment: can I know , which version of laravel are you using?
your code looks good.

Comment: Also do composer dump and php artisan cache clear, view clear

Comment: laravel version 5.4.21

Comment: Iam using 5.5 and it is working fine for me. please update and try. if it is not works, check my answer and try it. still not working, very sorry. without seeing your whole code, cant do anything. check my answer toooo

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately, I cannot show the code or cannot update laravel version without permission of Administration. So please post your answer. I will go through it.

Comment: added my answer. check it in answer's section

Comment: please dont forget to update, whether my answer is worked or facing any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defected htaccess file

```
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
    ##Redirect 301 /index.php https://www.example.net/
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [L,R=301]

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1 [P,L] 
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>
```

corrected htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]



    #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    ##Redirect 301 /index.php https://www.example.net/
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [L,R=301]


    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1 [P,L]
        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, working fine for me. couldn't able to find out the problem with your code based on the information given. if it is not working, please set the currentPage manullay in you controller. so you controller would be like

```
 public function getpages(Request $request) {
   Paginator::currentPageResolver(function() use ($request){
       return $request->page;
   });
   $variable=Model::paginate(10);
   dd($variable);
 }
```

Comment: No changes in result.

Comment: can you do `dd($request->all())` and post it.

Comment: added in description

Comment: please make sure, you used `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;` in your controller

Comment: see the latest description ( mention in above for dd($request->all()) )

Comment: yes, finally found the problem. thank god. :P use request validation to avoid such kind of issues.here the problem is parameter `page` is not passing to your controller.

Comment: so , how can i fixed that??

Comment: but of the code are same . the only difference is one is in live and another is in stage.

Comment: i got the proper issue here.In our whole site the passing to controller . and in validation . it is not mention how can i resolve this..

Comment: I really wanted to help you. but without debugging your, can not do anything.

Comment: i got the source right now. it was in htaccess file

Comment: got solution? then post it with your question. it will helpful